# Laravel Database Query returns collection of objects - how do I get the values to display?

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I guess there is a simple solution to my problem, I'm just a beginner :D

On one of my controllers I have a fairly complex DB request (see below) that returns a collection of objects and not an array (and I think I cannot perform the request with Eloquent?). Now I don't know how I get these values to actually display inside my blade page? Do I have to somehow convert it to an array to do that?

Thank you very much!

---

Part of TagsController.php:

```
$tags = DB::table('tags AS ta')
        ->select('ta.name')
        ->join('tag_thread AS tt', 'tt.tag_id', '=', 'ta.id')
        ->join(DB::raw('(select * from threads order by id desc limit 2000) th'), 'tt.thread_id', '=', 'th.id')
        ->groupBy('ta.name')
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('count(ta.name)'), 'DESC')
        ->limit(5)
        ->get();
```

return $tags:

```
[
    {
        "name": "javascript"
    },
    {
        "name": "jquery"
    },
    {
        "name": "php"
    }
]
```

Comment: Try `tags->implode('name', ', ')`

Comment: You can echo the values using object notation, ex: `{{$item->name}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pluck()` to get specific columns in array.

```
$tags = DB::table('tags AS ta')
        ->select('ta.name')
        ->join('tag_thread AS tt', 'tt.tag_id', '=', 'ta.id')
        ->join(DB::raw('(select * from threads order by id desc limit 2000) th'), 'tt.thread_id', '=', 'th.id')
        ->groupBy('ta.name')
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('count(ta.name)'), 'DESC')
        ->limit(5)
        ->pluck('name');
```

This will output like below and simply use `@foreach ()` in blade

```
[
    "name1",
    "name2",
    "name3",
]
```

Comment: great, worked perfectly! thank you so much! How would I do it if I wouldn't want a 'specific' column?

Comment: @Hillcow to retrieve all columns in `select`, just use `get()` as you written in question.  To manipulate more, can refer on [query results details](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results)

Comment: yes, but I was unable to retrieve any results from it (error: "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given")

Comment: show me the blade file and you should pass the tags to view using `return view('your.blade.php', compact('tags'))`

Comment: this is precisely what I am doing. inside blade:
    @foreach($tags as $tag)
                 {{ $tag }}
            @endforeach

Answer (score 0):

use `json_encode()` first to get the json from your result data, and then use `json_decode()` to convert the json data into array. so your final result will be a multidimensional array.

```
$tags=json_decode(json_encode($tags,true),true);
```

Then you can print the data in your blade as

```
@foreach ($tags as $tag)
    <div>{{ $tag['name'] }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your blade template, you can just loop through them with:

```
@foreach ($tags as $tag)
    <div>{{ $tag->name }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@foreach` statement in your views to iterate the Collection

```
@foreach($tags as $tag)
    <li>{{ $tag->name }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention, this is what I was doing (according to the laravel documentation) and the result is: "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"

Answer (score 0):

you can do with two ways with the collection object get value like below-:

```
  @foreach($tags as $value)

{{$value->name}}

@endforeach
```

or you can do with toArray function. just put the toArray function after the query like so

```
     get()->toArray();
```

and then use

```
    @foreach($tags as $value)

  {{$value['name']}}

     @endforeach
```